# Sum of power series using derivation or integration

Tags: calculus, power-series

could anyone help with this question?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(x-\frac{1}{2})^{n+1}}{n(n+1)}$$

I have to find sum of this power series using differentiation or integration.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: The operation is called "differentiation". A "derivation" is a calculation or proof of a result. (Or an object from algebraic geometry, which is also not what you mean.)

Comment: Thanks, I will edit question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that:
$$\frac{\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+1}}{n(n+1)}=\int_{0}^{x-\frac{1}{2}}\frac{y^n}{n}dy.$$ 
Then:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(x-\frac{1}{2})^{n+1}}{n(n+1)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{x-\frac{1}{2}}\frac{y^n}{n}dy = \\ = \int_{0}^{x-\frac{1}{2}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{y^n}{n}dy = -\int_{0}^{x-\frac{1}{2}}\log(1-y)dy = \\
= -\left((y-1)(\log(1-y)-1)\right)_{0}^{x-\frac{1}{2}} = \\=-\left(\log\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)-1\right)\left(x - \frac{3}{2}\right)+1.$$

References:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions

Comment: There appears to be a sign error in the last expression.

Comment: Nice answer! +1

Comment: @Dr.MV thanks for the advice, I fixed it.

Comment: You're welcome. My pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiate with respect to $x$ twice:
$$ S''(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (x-1/2)^{n-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (x-1/2)^{k}, $$
geometric series formula gives
$$ S''(x) = \frac{1}{1-(x-1/2)} = \frac{1}{3/2-x}. $$
Now you have to integrate this twice to get the answer, using (which you should check) $S(1/2)=S'(1/2)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiate the sum $S(x)$ once reveals that

$$S'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\, \frac{(x-1/2)^n}{n}$$

which we recognize as the series representation of $\log(1-(x-1/2))$.

Integrate once and apply the condition that $S(1/2)=0$.